# Problem using Siri to play radio on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, siri

[Use Siri to play music or podcasts](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208279)

The Apple help page suggests using Siri to “play BBC radio” - however this isn’t working - BBC radio is not available on Apple Music at the moment.

Have I missed something or are apple suggesting something that can’t be done?

[image]

Comment: That page provides examples of **how** you might ask, not necessarily exact stations/networks. I mean how many cities have a "Z100" or a "Beats 1?" Just because it is an example doesn't mean it's available to you. Heck it may be restricted by the BBC to only certain countries.

Comment: Have you tried these commands? What’s the error message? They work for me (streamed using tunein and iheartradio apps). @SteveChambers Beats 1 shouldn’t be regional, it’s apple’s original station.

Comment: @Steve Chambers both Z100 and Beats 1 are valid radio stations on Apple Music. Whereas BBC radio is not.

Comment: @JBallin I get “couldn’t find BBC radio in your music”

Comment: I don't have "TuneIn" installed, but you could try installing the app and see if that fixes it (for bbc radio). Can you confirm you're using latest iOS?